# Unable to send email in live server in codeingiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, model-view-controller

[Error screentshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFiyu.png) Hello guyz i am doing sending mail function in codeingniter, Same email function working in localhost but it did not work in live server i cant understand this error please help me..
This is my Email code:

```
$config = array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'email', // change it to yours
            'smtp_pass' => 'password', // change it to yours
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );

        $message =  "
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Verification Code</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h2>Thank you for Registering.</h2>
        <p>Your Account:</p>
        <p>Dear: ".$firstname."</p>
        <p>Please click the link below to activate your account.</p>
        <h4><a href='".base_url()."welcome/activate/".$id."/".$code."'>Activate My Account</a></h4>
        </body>
        </html>
        ";

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from($config['smtp_user']);
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('Signup Verification Email');
        $this->email->message($message);

        //sending email
        if($this->email->send()){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Register Successfull And your Activation link send in Email Please Verify Your Account');
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->email->print_debugger());

        }
```

ERROR:

```
Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

Comment: if($this->email->send()) after this if condition which part is executing...?
Also, does it shows any error, if yes then what is that?

Comment: i just put my error screenshot please check it @Shujaat sir

Comment: well, if you read the error, you'll see it's not your code but the mail server where the problem is. Gmail is actually rejecting to accept the email for delivery ("failed to authenticate password **please log in via your web browser and then try again** "). You probably are using the wrong gmail credentials (remember, gmail's outgoing servers don't permit un-authenticated sending), or perhaps you have 2FA enabled or something.

Comment: having said that, you should be using (IIRC) port 587 and TLS/StartTLS instead of SSL on port 465... The same error message being displayed on your site points to [this google support resource](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754) which has more information on how to proceed

Comment: Please post code *and errors* as text and not a screenshot. This will maximize our ability to help you.

Comment: Thank You @JavierLarroulet sir,so how to authenicate in my server help me

Comment: i put my error in please check it @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle

Comment: Why you are using gmail to send your email?

Comment: Then Which server can i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are showing is not related to your code rather its `authentication` error mean google servers are not allowing you to sign in. 
Now in order to run this code, make sure you are using the right username and password. 
After that, you have to turn on "[Allow less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)" option from your Google/Gmail account.

After that, your code should be able to send an email.

Also, When you have uploaded your script into web host then you should use the email address of your domain name, like `support@yourDomain.com` it looks more professional.

Given below code is fully working code. Before you run it you must create an email address like `admin@yourDomain.com` from your hosting panel where there will be an option of email management.

```
$this->load->library('email');
$encodeEmail = bin2hex('email@gmail.com']);
$this->email->from('admin@yourDomain.com', 'Your Domain');
$this->email->to('email@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Verification Required');
$url = site_url() . 'verify/' . $data['verification'] . '/' . $encodeEmail;

$message = "";
$message .= "You have signed up with our website \r\n";
$message .= "Please click on given below link to verify and activitate your account. \r\n" . $url;

$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: thank you so much, i will configure email on my server..your answer is very helpful for me